# Display each character of a string on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to jQuery and I'm trying to display the letter of a string when a button is clicked. I'd like it so that each time the button is clicked, the value displayed is "b" then "ba" then "bar", but right now when the button is clicked the only thing that displays is "b". Here is my code - any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(".letter").on('click', function(event){

  var foo = "bar"
  var split = foo.split('');
  $('.answer').val(split[0]);
  split.splice(0,1);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code use the length of the ouput instead of an internal counter

```
    var foo = 'bar';
    $(".letter").on('click', function (event) {
        $('.answer').val(foo.substring(0,$('.answer').val().length +1));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DXBAV/2/)

This has little to do with jQuery.  You just need a bit more JavaScript - you need to store the current index somewhere, and increment it in your handler

```
var index = -1;
$(".letter").on('click', function(event){
  var foo = "bar"

  if (index == foo.length - 1) return;
  $('.answer').val($('.answer').val() + foo.charAt(++index));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a counter! Everytime you click, it displays the substringed version!

```
var count = 1;
$(".letter").on('click', function(event){
    var foo = "bar";
    if (count < foo.length) { //set an if so that it stops incrementing
        var split = foo.substr(0,count);
        $('.answer').val(split);
        count++;
    } else {
        $(".answer").val(foo);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make foo and split global and you're done :D

```
var foo = "bar"
var split = foo.split('');

$(".letter").on('click', function(event){

  alert(split[0]);
  split.splice(0,1);


});
```

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dty3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why even split it, just do a substring with the counter idea

Set a counter!

```
    var count = 2;
    $(".letter").on('click', function(event){
      var foo = "bar"
      $('.answer').val(foo.substring(1,count));
      count++
    });
```

Comment: Why are you starting the index at 1?